# How i can define two constructors for a struct with different arguments in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, struct, arguments

I would define two types of struct in the same class, a constructor with three arguments and another with two arguments like this:

```
template<class A, class B, class C>
struct test{
test(A,B,C);
};

template<class A, class B>
struct test{
test(A,B);
};
```

In class main, when i create an instance of test with two arguments it is okay but when i create an instance of test with three arguments it throws an error: "too many arguments for model of class test".

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: And what's the problem? What do you actually try to solve with such template struct definitions? Note, that you have just two different, completely unrelated templates using the same class name.

Comment: That's not possible. It might be possible to solve your problem with *specialization*, but *what is your problem*? I mean, what is the *actual* problem you need to solve with code like that? Why do you think it would solve that problem? Right now this is too much of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info) for us to help you with your original problem (which might have other solutions).

Comment: Are you trying to have one `test` struct with two constructors or two different `test` structs?

Comment: C++ provides [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) and [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair).  Do those suffice for your use case?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.  What are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: This is commonly called an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Your question isn't about a real problem that programmers have.  It appears to be the answer to some problem, which isn't working, and you are asking how to make your answer to an unknown question correct.

Comment: I edited my question, my problem is that i can't create an instance of test with three arguments !!

Comment: @Yksisarvinen,  yes one test struct with two constructors : the first with two arguments and the second with three arguments

Comment: Right now you have two different and distinct structure templates, both named the same. This isn't allowed. Perhaps use a *non* template structure, and make the constructors templates? Or just plain overloading of the constructors? Since we still don't know the actual underlying problem you want to solve, we can't really help you.

Answer (score 1):

You just do:

```
template<class A, class B, class C>
struct test{
    test(A,B,C);
    test(A,B);
};
```

Comment: @AnoopRana `struct test` is always a type with 3 template parameters. The number of arguments in the constructor do not change that fact. So `test<int, int> t2(4,4);` is wrong, you need `test<int, int, int> t2(4,4);`or something. Giving only 2 parameters can only work if the 3rd parameter can be deduced. But since `C` isn't used that won't happen. You can add a deduction guide to make it happen though and then your type would be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've made some effort(even though incorrect), i would try to provide an answer according to my understanding of the question which is that you want to provide 2 separate constructors for your class template one of which has 2 parameters while the other has 3 parameters. You can do so as shown below. The explanation is given as comments in the below example.

```
template<class A, class B, class C>
struct test{
    //declaration for constructor one 
    test(A,B,C);
    
    //declaration for constructor two
    test(A,B);
};

//implementation for constructor one 
template<class A, class B, class C> 
test<A,B,C>::test(A a, B b, C c)
{
    std::cout<<"constructor with 3 parameters called"<<std::endl;
}
//implementation for constructor two 
template<class A, class B, class C> 
test<A,B,C>::test(A a, B b)
{
    std::cout<<"constructor with 2 parameters called"<<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    test<int, double, int> t1(2,2,3);//calls constructor with 3 parameters
    
    test<int, double, int> t2(2,2);//calls constructor with 2 parameters
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/hvySpqhl8_)